sublime text, marking tab as non-editable
How can I prevent accidental edits in Sublime Text when working with multiple files?
I often have multiple versions of the 'same' file open in Sublime Text (e.g., a current version and a reference version). However, I often mistakenly edit the old reference version instead of the new one. Is there a way to mark a tab as 'read-only' in Sublime Text to avoid accidental changes? Alternatively, are there any plugins or built-in features that may help manage this kind of situation effectively? Its quite cumbersome to mark files non editable in the file system.

Quite old, but works well for me: https://github.com/ivellioscolin/sublime-plugin-readonlyprotect. (not answering since this Q is likely closeable as asking for recommendations)
